# How to handle situation with IAP internet loss

Tags: ios, networking, in-app-purchase

I have one button in my app, which is supposed to show the price of item, then if you tap on it you can buy an item. Initially that button is disabled and has no price on it. After application is launched, I'm trying to fetch item information and if successful show the price/enable button.

If there is no internet, fetching will fail and button will remain disabled. Internet can be on again while I'm in application and by going to background.

What I want to ask, what are my choices to re-issue fetching again, where can I do it? Would it be good to put some button so user can manually trigger re-fetching or there are other common practices to solve that issue?

Comment: What about whenever internet reachability changes to available and when your app is launched/is opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to monitor Internet reachability, both when you initially want to get the price and if it changes while your app is running. Take a look at this library: [by tonymillion](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability).